# SSIS : How to process a UTF-8 file which has no Byte Order Mark?

Tags: file, utf-8, ssis, connection, byte-order-mark

I'm using a Flat File Connection to read a file. This file contains UTF-8 data, but the file does not have a Byte Order Mark. (I checked this with notepad++)

The CodePage from the flat file connection is set to '65001' and UniCode is set to 'False'.

While processing this file and copying the data to the database, some characters are wrong.

What is the best/easiest solution ?

1. Change some settings on the flat file connection ? (This will
   probably also mean that I need to change the codepage from the
   columns.)
2. Manually add the Byte Order Mark to the file before processing?
3. Something else ?

Comment: Why do you think that Byte Order Mark is the reason for some characters being copied wrongly?

Comment: The database table was defined as varchar instead of nvarchar, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database table was defined as **varchar** instead of **nvarchar**, this solved my problem.